# Removing an object in a child collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've got a collection of content. Said collection has a collection of responses as such

```
Content : [{ 'id' : '1234', 
    'Responses' : [{
        'id' : '12345'
    }
```

etc. Now, I want to remove response 12345, but I don't want to remove all of the responses. I can't seem to find the command to do so. I'm getting the impression that the correct action is to grab the object, rebuild the Responses without the one I want removed, and then save the Content object as a whole. Provided there are many responses, this seems like a bad practice to have to load the entire object that way.

Comment: Can you format that any better? It seems like you have multiple arrays in there. What's considered a content? I understand you can have multiple responses. Before I attempt to answer, I want to be able to understand your question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pull` is what you are looking for. See for more in the documentation:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

Comment: FYI: Link is now dead.